# Kendo MVC Grid - How to make cell Editable based on a model value

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

Our Kendo Grid DataSource looks like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(10)
.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
.Model(model =>
    {
     model.Id(m => m.MilestoneId);
     model.Field(m => m.ProjectName).Editable(false);
     model.Field(m => m.Name).Editable(false);
     model.Field(m => m.Status).Editable(??????);
    })
```

For the last field (`Status`) we need to provide a bool value for `Editable`. However, I would like this value to come from the value of a property on our model. The model has a property called `IsAvailable` and I would like the bool to be that value.

Basically we only want the Status column to be editable if `IsAvailable` is true in the model.

The C# code on the model for that property is:

```
public bool IsAvailable{ get; set; }
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to  access this value?

I have tried:

```
model.Field(m => m.Status).Editable((model.Field(m => m.IsAvailable).ToString()).AsBool());
```

which compiles but does not work; it is always returning false for all cases.

Comment: What does "does not work" exactly mean? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I edited your question, for `Code` we press the code indent button in the text editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Timothy Walter's link](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit), I found a solution to the issue, by using the edit event as he suggested.

Here is what my code ended up looking like:

```
.Events(events =>
    {
        events.Edit("edit_handler");
    })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(10)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.MilestoneId);
            model.Field(m => m.ProjectName).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.Name).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.Status).Editable(true);
        })
```

and the Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function edit_handler(e) {

    if (!e.model.isNew()) {            
        var statusDropDown = e.container.find("input[name=Status]").data("kendoDropDownList");

        if (!e.model.IsAvailable) {
            statusDropDown.enable(false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since you've found your own answer, you can mark it as accepted to let people know that this was the best thing that worked for you!

Comment: great solution!  came in handy

Answer (score 3):

It is probably easier to enable editing of this field by default, and attach to the "edit" event and disable the edit field based on the data for the current row as needed.

For an example look at the docs for the [edit event on the grid](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit).